# Single touch to move and double finger touch to resize Image view

Tags: android, image-resizing, ontouchlistener, multi-touch

I want to single touch listener to move object (Image View rect) and double finger to resize image

Try:

```
rect.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = rect.getLayoutParams();
            float lasty = 0f;
            float lastx = 0f;
            final float distheight = event.getRawY() - lasty;
            final float distwidth = event.getRawX() - lastx;

            Log.d("MotionTouch:", "finger: " + event.getPointerCount());

            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Log.d("MotionTouch:","ACTION_DOWN");
                    dx = v.getX() - event.getRawX();
                    dy = v.getY() - event.getRawY();
                    lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN;
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    Log.d("MotionTouch:","ACTION_MOVE");
                    v.animate().x(event.getRawX() + dx).y(event.getRawY() + dy).setDuration(0).start();
                    break;


                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:

                    Log.d("MotionTouch:","ACTION_POINTER_DOWN");
                    lp.height -= distheight;
                    lp.width -= distwidth;
                    rect.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    Log.d("MotionTouch:","ACTION_POINTER_UP");
                    lp.height += distheight;
                    lp.width += distwidth;
                    rect.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    break;

                default:

                    return true;
            }

           /* v.invalidate();
            v.requestLayout();*/
            return true;
        }
    });
```

It works but when two finger touches(MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN case run then hide) then it hide Image View (rect)

why it hide touch object(ImageView rect)

rect is rectangle image view.

Comment: Basically you want pinch-to-zoom .. Right?

Comment: pinch-to-zoom in height and width increase/decrease simultaneously but i don't want simultaneously and then set imageview that position @UmangBurman